# Simple regex formula in VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net

Need regex that replaces all occurences of '%xx' with ', ' 
where xx can be digit or letter:

example:

```
Item%20One%0AItem%20Two%0AItem%20Three
```

translates to

```
Item One, Item Two, Item Three
```

Comment: Isn't there an URL decoder class/function in vb.net?

Comment: I agree with hjpotter92, the string you have given is url encoded, and thus rather than trying to reinvent the wheel and implement your own url decoding function using regexes, just look for an existing solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt(v=vs.110).aspx) method.